# WordPress change content without reload

Tags: ajax, wordpress, url, text

I have a wordpress theme in which i have to create a page that has a movie that goes loop.
it has 3 menu points which change the div text without reloading the page.

So far no problem.

```
<a href="javscript:void(0);" onclick="getdata('text.php','content2');">Click here – put it in content box 2</a>
```

But when im on a different page and i click for example the second link, it should go to the video page and change the text to the second one.

How can i do this?

Is there a way to do that with?

```
url/wordpressname/#1
```

Comment: You could add your solution as an answer, and flag it as "accepted". That way the question won't stay open :)

Comment: yes, i forgot that, i still have to wayt for a day to answer my own question. thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Solution: i found a solution here: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/how-to-ajaxify-wordpress-theme.html

which i changed to fit my needs:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $mainContent = $("#text"),
        siteUrl = "http://" + top.location.host.toString(),
        url = '';

    $(document).delegate("a[href^='"+siteUrl+"']:not([href*=/wp-admin/]):not([href*=/wp-login.php]):not([href$=/feed/])", "click", function() {
        //location.hash = this.pathname;
        //return false;
    }); 

    $("#searchform").submit(function(e) {
        location.hash = '?s=' + $("#s").val();
        e.preventDefault();
    }); 

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
        url = window.location.hash.substring(1); 

        if (!url) {
            return;
        } 


        if (url=="1") {
            $mainContent.html('<p>Text1</>');
        } 

        if (url=="2") {
            $mainContent.html('<p>Text2</>');
        } 

        if (url=="3") {
            $mainContent.html('<p>Text3</>');
        } 

        if (url=="4") {
            $mainContent.html('<p>Text4</>');
        } 


       // url = url + "#content"; 

        //$mainContent.animate({opacity: "0.1"}).html('<p>Please wait...</>').load(url, function() {
            //$mainContent.animate({opacity: "1"});
        //});
    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```